# How to convert a vector of vectors into a vector of slices without creating a new object?

Tags: vector, rust, slice

I have a vector of vectors. I would like to transform it into a vector of slices without creating a new object:

```
let mut a: Vec<Vec<u8>> = vec![vec![0; 8]; msg.len()];
let mut new: Vec<&[u8]> = Vec::new();

for i in 0..a.len() {
    a[i] = foo(i);
}

for i in 0..a.len() {
    new.push(&a[i]);
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: In addition to what is said in the duplicate, remember that slices only _borrow_ the data they point to and ask yourself who would _own_ that data once you replaced the original vectors?